# Is it possible to dynamically increment in a for-loop in C++?

Tags: c++, dynamic, for-loop

I was wondering if it is possible to dynamically increment in a for-loop in C++. For example, I have the following code:

```
for (int x = 0; x < maxX-1; x ++){
    for (int y = 0; y < maxY-1; y ++){
        for (int z = 0; z < maxZ-1; z++){
             cout << "z = " << z << endl;
        }   
    }
}
```

Which prints out

```
z = 0
z = 1
z = 2
...
```

However, if I were to change the loop to:

```
    amount = 2;
for (int x = 0; x < maxX-1; x ++){
    for (int y = 0; y < maxY-1; y ++){
        for (int z = 0; z < maxZ-amount; z+= amount){
             cout << "z = " << z << endl;
        }   
    }
}
```

Then I get an infinite loop of

```
z = 0
z = 0
z = 0
z = 0
```

Is it not possible to do this?

Comment: Is it an infinite loop or is the Z-loop just iterating once before terminating? This might happen if maxZ is 4 or less.

Comment: It was a case of maxZ being erroneously set to the wrong value, which I should have caught. Glad that I know for sure that this is possible though :)

Comment: Are you sure the increment is not really written as `z + amount`? - Or another possibility: `amount` is 0 despite what you think.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly possible. What's more likely is that you have an integer overflow/underflow bug.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why the above code doesn't work.As Rhuidean said may be the z loop is iterating and also it depends upon the values of maxX,maxY and maxZ.

Answer (score 0):

it's perfectly possible.

The code you submitted doesn't create an ininite loop.

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    int amount = 2;

    int maxX = 4;
    int maxY = 5;
    int maxZ = 12;

    for (int x = 0; x < maxX-1; x ++){
        for (int y = 0; y < maxY-1; y ++){
            for (int z = 0; z < maxZ-amount; z+= amount){
             cout << "z = " << z << endl;
        }   
    }
}
}
```

http://codepad.org/TZtTFdnD

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you are creating a maintenance headache as the code gets very difficult to follow.

I think you should rethink your strategy.